# Delay of 20 milliseconds in the left channel of an audio file (e.g mp3) using ffmpeg?

Tags: javascript, audio, ffmpeg, howler.js, soundeffect

How do I make a delay of 20 milliseconds in the left channel of an audio file (e.g mp3) using ffmpeg ??

I usually enable this option under ffdshow audio processor while playing audio using MPC-HC

**Is it possible to do the same in **howlerjs** (a strong textjavascript audio library) ? (I mean this audio effect)**

[image]

Somewhat like this kind of effect: **Just delay the either channel by 20ms** Like we do in Adobe Audition
[image]

Answer (score 2):

Use the [adelay filter](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#adelay):

```
ffmpeg -i input.mp3 -af "adelay=20|0" output.mp3
```

Answer (score 0):

You could grab the left source of the file, add delay using `-itsoffset` and mix the final output https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/AudioChannelManipulation.